SpeechDetected Event never raised by NAO
I have defined a speech detector as follows:
class SpeechDetector(object):
    """
            Class for Speech detection
    """
    def __init__(self, session):
        super(SpeechDetector, self).__init__()

        self.memory = session.service("ALMemory")

        self.subscriber_user_started_speaking = self.memory.subscriber("ALSpeechRecognition/Status")
        self.subscriber_user_started_speaking.signal.connect(self.on_user_ongoing_speech)
        self.speech_detection = session.service("ALSpeechRecognition")
        self.speech_detection.subscribe("SpeechDetector")
        self.user_is_speaking = False

        print ("Starting Speech Detector")

    def on_user_ongoing_speech(self, value):
        print(value)
        # statuses are  Idle, ListenOn, SpeechDetected, EndOfProcess, ListenOff, Stop.
        if value == "SpeechDetected":
            print("User is speaking now!")
            self.user_is_speaking = True
        elif value == "ListenOff" or value == "Stop" or value == "Idle" or value == "ListenOn":
            print("User has stopped speaking now!")
            self.user_is_speaking = False

But the SpeechDetected value never gets caught, any idea why?

For NAO to begin to do anything, you must get his attention. "Hey Nao!"
When Nao lets you know he is tracking and listening to you, your code should now work. Here is a modified version I used to debug the issue. Use Ctrl-C to quit.
class SpeechDetector(object):
    """ SpeechDetector """

    def __init__(self, session):
        super(SpeechDetector, self).__init__()
        print('SpeechDetector constructor called()')
        self.tts = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
        self.memory = session.service("ALMemory")
        
        self.speech_detection = session.service("ALSpeechRecognition")
        self.speech_detection.subscribe("SpeechDetector")
        self.user_is_speaking = False
        
        self.subscriber_user_started_speaking = self.memory.subscriber("ALSpeechRecognition/Status")
        self.subscriber_user_started_speaking.signal.connect(self.on_user_ongoing_speech)
    
    def on_user_ongoing_speech(self, value):
        print(value)
        # statuses are  Idle, ListenOn, SpeechDetected, EndOfProcess, ListenOff, Stop.
        if value == "SpeechDetected":
            if self.user_is_speaking == False:
                self.tts.say('User is speaking now!', _async=False)
            self.user_is_speaking = True
            time.sleep(10)
        elif value == "ListenOff" or value == "Stop" or value == "Idle" or value == "ListenOn":
            if self.user_is_speaking == True:
                self.tts.say('User has stopped speaking now!', _async=False)
            self.user_is_speaking = False 
            time.sleep(10)

    def exit(self):
        self.tts.say('SpeechDetector exiting', _async=False)
        os._exit(0)

    """ Loop on, wait for events until manual interruption. """
    def run(self):
        self.tts.say('Starting SpeechDetector', _async=False)
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(10)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Interrupted by user, stopping SpeechDetector")
            self.exit()
            sys.exit(0)

